# How to make a registration form correctly in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using the example in cookbook of Symfony to make a form with symfony 2.8 version: [example](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html)

i have the same code like in the example...
But I get the next error: Neither the property "plainPassword" nor one of the methods "plainPassword()", "getplainPassword()"/"isplainPassword()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" in register.html.twig at line 7

how can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

plainPassword

This field is not persisted: (notice no @ORM\Column above it). It temporarily stores the plain password from the registration form. This field can be validated and is then used to populate the password field.

see more on: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html

```
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $plainPassword
     */
    public function setPlainPassword($plainPassword)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check and add into your Entity public method, for example:

```
public function getPlainPassword()
{
    return $this->plainPassword;
}
```